# actionscript-how to stop movieclip

Tags: actionscript-2

I made a movie clip object namely "ball" with this script and it works!

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){
var a=1.2 //it's an acceleration
totalTime = getTimer()/1000;
hours = Math.floor(totalTime/3600);
  minutes = Math.floor((totalTime/3600-hours)*60);
seconds = Math.floor(((totalTime/3600-hours)*60-minutes)*60);
milli = Math.floor((totalTime-(seconds+(minutes*60)+(hours*3600)))*100);
stopwatch = seconds+(milli/100)+(minutes*60)+(hours*3600);
t= stopwatch;
v=a*t;
this._x=this._x+v;
 }
```

but I failed to stop with button contains this script,

```
on (press) {
    _root.ball.stop();
}
```

Anyone can help me please? I want to stop the object and the timer also. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `stop()` makes the timeline within the ball MovieClip stop playing, it does not have a relationship with the position of the ball or any logic associated with manoeuvring it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just stop the using stop(), read Marty's comment.

First of all, change the code within your `ball` movieclip to this:

```
onClipEvent(load){
    _stopped = false;
}

onClipEvent(enterFrame){
    var a=1.2 //it's an acceleration

    if(_stopped == false){
        totalTime = getTimer()/1000;
        hours = Math.floor(totalTime/3600);
        minutes = Math.floor((totalTime/3600-hours)*60);
        seconds = Math.floor(((totalTime/3600-hours)*60-minutes)*60);
        milli = Math.floor((totalTime-(seconds+(minutes*60)+(hours*3600)))*100);
        stopwatch = seconds+(milli/100)+(minutes*60)+(hours*3600);
        t= stopwatch;
        v=a*t;
        this._x=this._x+v;
    }
}
```

This wraps the code which does all the calculation and movement of your ball, inside an if statement, which is only true when the variable `_stopped` is equals to `FALSE`. As long as `_stopped = false;`, your ball will be moving, and so will the time.

Now, change your button's actionscript to this:

```
on (press) {
    _root.ball._stopped = true;
}
```

This will turn `_stopped`'s value from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, and thus stopping all the calculation and movement of your ball, since the condition that `_stopped` should be equals to `FALSE`, is then no longer true.

Hope this works :)